# Prevent Multiple Instances of Java Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, visibility

The application that I am working on involves frames that are created from a JPanel based upon what the user selects. I am trying to prevent a user from launching multiple instances of the same frame if the select the same item twice. Here is the condition what I wrote for that purpose.

Main class:

```
public void showPieGraphFrame()
{
    final PieGraph gPieGraph = new PieGraph("Traffic Type Distribution", counterOne, counterTwo);
    gPieGraph.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.positionFrameOnScreen(gPieGraph, 0.35, 0.03);

    if(!gPieGraph.isVisible())  
    {
    gPieGraph.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

PieGraph class that I want to prevent multiple instances of:

```
public class PieGraph extends ApplicationFrame implements ActionListener {

    public PieGraph(final String title) {
        super(title);

        // create a menubar
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        // create a dataset...
        final PieDataset dataset = trafficTypeDataset();

        // create the chart...
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

        // add the chart to a panel...
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(width, height));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final PieDataset dataset) {

        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Test Chart", dataset, false, false, false);

        final PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();

        return chart;
    }
```

However, it is not working and you can still launch the same frame more than once. How can I prevent this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: So, any chance of seeing that SSCCE any time soon, or are you intending to leave us to guess why your code is broken?

Comment: This is the first that I've heard of the SSCCE concept and I'm not sure what other details I may have omitted that you're looking for.

Comment: Well, out of 'SSCCE' you've so far achieve 'S'.  Try for the ***rest..***

Comment: Not sure how to post a self-contained example given that I currently have 1800 lines of code across 7 classes.

Comment: Remove 1650 LOC, demote the non-main classes to default access and add them into the end of the public class source file.  I reckon I could turn this problem into an SSCCE in 30-40 LOC.

Comment: I added a chunk of the non-main class for the particular frame containing a PieGraph that I am trying to prevent multiple instances of.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I prevent this?

Swap the frame to a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option. The frame contains a graph and JMenuBar.

Comment: *"The frame contains a graph and JMenuBar."*  Why on earth does an element popped out of a GUI need it's own menus?  You seem to be going about this all wrong.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for some basic tips.

Comment: I have been thinking of switching to a JInternalFrame instead of what I have now. Thanks for pointing out that what I'm trying to do probably isn't a good approach. I'm still curious to see if there's a way to do what I asked though.

Comment: If THE DOCTOR insists, there is no problem. A JDialog can also have a JMenuBar.

Comment: *"I'm still curious to see if there's a way to do what I asked though."*  Possibly.  I expect the reason for the current failure was identified by  @GiovaniGuizzo *"Two windows will only appear when you have two JFame objects."*  Which makes me think that somewhere outside that snippet, there is code (that allows) for more than one frame to be created.  But short of seeing the SSCCE, I really cannot say for sure.

Comment: @andrew I'm more curious as to way a window having a JMenuBar would prevent you from using a JDialog?

Answer (score 2):

It simple doesn't allow you to call `setVisible` twice. Two windows will only appear when you have two `JFame` objects. Make your `JFrame` a `Singleton`.
Hope I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Singleton Pattern for the frame, e.g:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame() {

 private static MainFrame instance;

 public static MainFrame getInstance(//parameters) {
   if (instance == null){
    instance = new MainFrame(//parameters)
 }
    return instance;
 }

 private MainFrame(//parameters){}

}
```